# SpringBoot app. running Tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file, but I have some problems running the Junit tests in Eclipse

I have this config file in the app.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserSecurityService userSecurityService;

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Value("${server.contextPath}")
    private String serverContextPath;

..
}
```

and in the test folder:

```
@Configuration
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class TestSystemConfig {

}
```

and this Test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestSystemConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class DriverServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    protected DriverService driverService;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(driverService.findAll());
    }
}
```

but when I run the tests I got this error:

```
2018-01-16 14:25  [main] ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@214b199c] to prepare test instance [com.telefonica.backend.service.DriverServiceTests@2b72cb8a]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.telefonica.config.SecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userSecurityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.telefonica.backend.service.UserSecurityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:667)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.telefonica.config.SecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userSecurityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.telefonica.backend.service.UserSecurityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1088)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredMethodElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.telefonica.config.SecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userSecurityService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.telefonica.backend.service.UserSecurityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:508)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.getWebSecurityConfigurers(AutowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:130)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:50)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:348)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:121)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:262)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.telefonica.backend.service.UserSecurityService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TestSystemConfig.class` does not have proper spring context configuration. It cannot scan your service classes being autowired.

#### Here is one simple spring solution **without** `TestSystemConfig.class`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringApplication.class) // your main class normally with @SpringBootApplication annotation
public class DriverServiceTests{
    @Autowired
    protected DriverService driverService;

    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {

        System.out.println(driverService.findAll());
    }

}
```

#### To enable MVC testing and reuse the test config:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = SpringApplication.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "test" }) // It is recommended to have a test profile for your integration test
public abstract class ParentTest {

}
```

Let your test class extend this Parent test class:

```
public class DriverServiceTest extends ParentTest{
    @Autowired
    protected DriverService driverService;
    
    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(driverService.findAll());
    }
    
    // test with security
    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "Mikasa", roles = {"captain"})
    public void kill_withCaptain_titanKilled(){
        // test if users with role "captain" can kill the titan
        // there are certain requirements for your security config in order to use @WithMockUser, please take a look at spring doc for more details.
    }
}
```

Note that `SpringApplication.class` is the Main class generally with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.